# deleting files with case statement in shell script

Tags: shell, ksh

I have written a small shell script to remove all the files in a directory except a few.

```
#! /bin/ksh

logFile=/home/user/testscrpt/testlogfile.txt
echo "$logFile"
  for rmdir in *
  do

    case "$rmdir" in
      'rndp'|"$logFile"|'rndp1')
        continue
        ;;

      *)
        if [ -d "$rmdir" ]
        then
          rm -rf "$rmdir"
        elif [ -f "$rmdir" ]
        then
          rm -f "$rmdir"
        fi
        ;;
    esac
  done
```

But after executing the script, i can see that the file which i didn't wanted to delete (/home/user/testscrpt/testlogfile.txt) is also getting deleted.
Please correct me if i am doing any mistake in the script here.

Comment: Did you mean `break` instead of `continue`? Your logic now continues even if the current file matches your log file (testlogfile.txt) and deletes it. If you'd like to exclude the patterns, you need to give `break`

Comment: Break here will break the case statement when i match any of the above listed file or directories.
I have used continue so that if matches any of the file/ directory mentioned in pattern 1 it will skip that file and continue with the next file.

Comment: but if you continue, you are essentially allowing it to match the logfile pattern and delete that as well isn't it? I just tested this with break and it does not delete the files matching your pattern in `'rndp'|"$logFile"|'rndp1'` or were you hoping to delete these?

Comment: Except these 3 files delete all the files. Basically the variable is  not getting substituted properly here.

Comment: The `continue` here isn't doing anything. The loop contains no contents after the `case` statement so continuing the loop in that `case` block is no different than having the `case` statement end normally and hit the end of the loop.

Comment: The problem here is likely that `$rmdir` isn't a full path and so will never match `$logfile`. The glob is going to complete to bare file names (which you know because of the `rndp` and `rndp1` bits of that `case` match.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$rmdir` will not be an absolute path; it will only contain the basename `testlogfile.txt`.

You need to chdir to the directory first: you do not want to start recursively deleting the wrong files (I speak from experience here)

```
#! /bin/ksh

cd /home/user/testscrpt
logFile=testlogfile.txt

for rmdir in *;  do
    case "$rmdir" in
        rndp|"$logFile"|rndp1)
            echo "keeping $rmdir"
            continue
            ;;
        *)
            echo "deleting $rmdir"
            rm -rf "$rmdir"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Tested doesn't work. It seems there is some problem with the variable substitution in ksh in case patterns.http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/90311-help-variable-substitution-case-statement.html

Comment: What version of ksh are you running? what's your OS?

Comment: The scenario you link is different to your: in the linked problem, the special character "|" is part of the variable value, so it loses it's special meaning. Not so here.

Comment: ksh version and OS                                                                        $ echo $KSH_VERSION
Version JM 93t+ 2010-06-21


$ cat /etc/issue

Welcome to SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP4  (x86_64) - Kernel \r (\l).

Comment: The syntax here will not pose a problem for ksh93. The error must be in the logic of your code.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

```
  pushd /home/user/testscript
  ls -d * | egrep -v '^(rndp1*|testlogfile.txt)$' | xargs rm -rf
  popd
```

and you might want to make the 'ls ...' into a function:

> files_to_rm () { ls -d * | egrep -v '^(rndp1*|testlogfile.txt)$'; }

so it's simply:

```
  pushd /... ; files_to_rm | xargs rm -fr ; popd
```

i find it useful to have a means of displaying a list before acting on it. 
and any way i can avoid life's sh-bangs reduces the pain.

Comment: Tested with the variable, but its not working.If we use the correct literal(testlogfile.txt) it works fine. In my case, i get the value at runtime, so can't hard code it to some constant literal.